# how to show empty list in listview?

Tags: android

i am using a normal activity where in i have a listview. when the array is empty, how do i show an empty view? i tried using a textview with the id android:empty but it only works with listactivity.
i am using a custom adapte(which extends the baseadapter class) for the listview and in the getcount() i return 0 when the array is null. But this is not working.
i want to show a empty listview when i have no rows in my array.
how do i achieve this?

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Consider using a ListView and extending ListAdapter, which provide support for the empty case.  Using these, a ListView element:

```
<ListView android:id="@+id/android:list" ... />
```

will display a matching

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/android:empty" ... />
```

for an empty list.

Answer (score 1):

Another tip I spent two hours figuring out. If you set the `layout_height` to `"0dip"` for the `TextView` as is sometimes recommended for efficiency, it won't show up unless you set the `layout_weight` to some value.

Answer (score 0):

You can call set list.setEmptyView(view) to display any view when the list is empty.